# App crashes whenever this HTTP is request made

Tags: android, api, kotlin

Whenever this code is executed, the app crashes and no data is returned.

I have already tried `Volley` and `okhttp` and neither worked.

```
val url = "https://..." 

val lines = URL(url).openStream().use {
    it.bufferedReader().readLines()        
}

outputText.text = lines.toString()
```

I expect to see the returned information but instead the app crashes.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: What error is returned?  Could you post it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your error log, I can only assume that you are getting the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` Exception.

If that's the case, You should know that in android you can't run network related actions on the main thread - you need to run them on a different thread, for example:

```
Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    try  {
    //Put your code that you want to run in here.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});

mThread.start
```